# Erlang Installation and "/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: could not read symbols: Bad value"

Tags: ssl, erlang, rabbitmq

I am trying to install RabbitMQ (3.6.1) on linux machine Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6. To install rabbitMQ , first I have installed Erlang R16B03 version from source (otp_src_R16B03) and followed below commands

```
wget http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B03.tar.gz
tar xvfz /usr/tmp/otp_src_R16B03.tar
cd otp_src_R16B03
LANG=C; export LANG
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin
```

I get the message shown below:

```
*********************************************************************
**********************  APPLICATIONS DISABLED  **********************
*********************************************************************

crypto         : OpenSSL is configured for kerberos but no krb5.h found
jinterface     : No Java compiler found
odbc           : ODBC library - link check failed
orber          : No C++ compiler found
ssh            : OpenSSL is configured for kerberos but no krb5.h found
ssl            : OpenSSL is configured for kerberos but no krb5.h found

*********************************************************************
*********************************************************************
**********************  APPLICATIONS INFORMATION  *******************
*********************************************************************

wx             : wxWidgets not found, wx will NOT be usable
*********************************************************************
```

though I continued with make & make install but while starting Rabbitmq server I get the following error

```
sbin/rabbitmq-server
```

Getting message

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {error,{missing_dependencies,[crypto,ssl],[mochiweb,cowlib,cowboy]}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /usr/tmp/rabbitmq_server-3.6.1/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit.log
   /usr/tmp/rabbitmq_server-3.6.1/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit-sasl.log

Stack trace:
   [{rabbit_plugins,ensure_dependencies,1,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_plugins.erl"},{line,179}]},
    {rabbit_plugins,prepare_plugins,1,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_plugins.erl"},{line,198}]},
    {rabbit,broker_start,0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,284}]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,303}]},
    {init,start_it,1,[]},
    {init,start_em,1,[]}]

{"init terminating in do_boot",{error,{missing_dependencies,[crypto,ssl],[mochiweb,cowlib,cowboy]}}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

After exploring multiple solution I understood that I need to install latest Openssl and provide the path of newly installed openssl.

I installed Openssl from the source and installed with -fPIC

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz /usr/tmp/openssl-1.0.2.tar.gz
cd /usr/tmp/openssl-1.0.2
./config -fPIC
make 
make install
```

Now new openssl is installed in bin/local/ssl location and I have reinstalled  the Erlang with below configuration

```
export PATH="/usr/local/ssl/bin:$PATH”
export CFLAGS=-fPIC
cd /usr/tmp/otp_src_RB1603
LANG=C; export LANG
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/bin
make
make install
```

now I get the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(rsaz_exp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: could not read symbols: Bad value**
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[6]: *** [../priv/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/crypto.so] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/otp_src_R16B03/lib/crypto/c_src'
make[5]: *** [release_spec] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/otp_src_R16B03/lib/crypto/c_src'
make[4]: *** [release] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/otp_src_R16B03/lib/crypto/c_src'
make[3]: *** [release] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/otp_src_R16B03/lib/crypto/c_src'
make[2]: *** [release] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/otp_src_R16B03/lib/crypto'
make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/otp_src_R16B03/lib'
make: *** [install.libs] Error 2
```

I could not resolve this error , any suggestion.. 
Please note I am using accessing machine as root user

Comment: Couldn't you just install the rpm package from rmq website?

Comment: thanks , it worked .. I install erlang rpm file and rabbitmq.rpm file

Comment: You are welcome! I'll put this as answer then.

Comment: Couldn't you just install the rpm package from rmq website?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(rsaz_exp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata'
> can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
> /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: could not read symbols: Bad value**
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

You need to build OpenSSL with the `shared` option. Maybe something like the following for a 64-bit Intel machine.

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0b.tar.gz
tar xzf openssl-1.1.0b.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.0b

./Configure no-ssl2 no-ssl3 shared enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128
...
make -j 8
...
make test
...
suod make install
```

`enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128` make EC Diffie-Hellman 2x to 4x faster, but it has some limitations. You are OK to use it on a 64-bit Intel machine. Also see [Compilation and Installation | Configure Options](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options) on the OpenSSL wiki.

---

Also, be sure to either `make dclean` for OpenSSL 1.0.2 and below; or `make distclean` for OpenSSL 1.1.0 and above. Otherwise, some of the old configuration lingers even after changing the option.